# Filtering output of foreign key data

Tags: django, foreign-keys, filtering

Since I am making a online futsal booking system, i am currently doing timeslot validation. If a timeslot is already booked, the user should not be able to book that timeslot again.

models.py

```
class futsals(models.Model):
    futsal_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    futsal_address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    owner_email = models.EmailField(max_length=25)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.futsal_name}'

    class timeslot(models.Model):
        timesslot = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        name  = models.CharField(max_length=15)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.timesslot}'

    class Booking(models.Model):
        user_book =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        futsal =  models.ForeignKey(futsals, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        time_slot = models.ForeignKey(timeslot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def validate_date(date):
            if date < timezone.now().date():
                raise ValidationError("Date cannot be in the past")

        booking_date = models.DateField( default=None, validators=[validate_date])

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user_book}'

    forms.py

    def timeslot_validation(value):  

        v = Booking.objects.all().values_list('time_slot')
        k = timeslot.objects.filter(pk__in=v)

        if value == k:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This timeslot is already booked!!")

        else:
            return value
```

But I am not able to do the validation. Since the output of variable 'k' looks like:

```
<QuerySet [<timeslot: 19:00 - 20:00>, <timeslot: 18:00 - 19:00>, <timeslot: 17:00 - 18:00>]>
```

The above shown timeslot is the timeslot booked by users. Now if another user enters this timeslot, it should show 'this timeslot is already booked.'

Now, I want this data to be shown as 
  [(19:00 - 20:00), (18:00 - 19:00), (17:00 - 18:00)]

Any help would be appreciated, or if anyone could provides me a better solution for validation?

Comment: the output of 'k' looks like:                                                                                                <QuerySet [<timeslot: 19:00 - 20:00>, <timeslot: 18:00 - 19:00>, <timeslot: 17:00 - 18:00>]>

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique constraint to the `time_slot` and `booking_date` field and your `ModelForm` will handle validating that the `time_slot` and `booking_date` is unique

```
class Booking(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('booking_date', 'time_slot'),
        )
```